# Executing code every time a laptop is plugged into, or unplugged from power

Tags: arch-linux, power-management

I'm looking to run some code every time my laptop is plugged into, or unplugged from power. I know this can be done; for example, GNOME hooks into this functionality (somehow) to update the battery indicator in my toolbar. The code I want to execute is a simple shell script which switches between the integrated and discrete GPU depending on whether external power is available (a wrapper around `gpu-switch`).

I'm specifically interested in knowing about ways to do this *other than* polling and parsing the output of e.g. `acpi -V` to determine whether the battery is charging or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `udev` rule that runs a script when the AC adapter is plugged and unplugged:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/powersave.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{online}=="0", RUN+="/path/to/your/script true"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{online}=="1", RUN+="/path/to/your/script false"
```

Comment: yep, but worth noting the script must be fast otherwise have the script spawn a backgroud process (long scripts in udev can make it miss events, see man page).